# query dies, but does the job

Tags: php

My query inserts the data in to the record but it also display query failed. It inserts the record into the database, but instead of redirecting to the calander page it display query failed.

```
//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO `customer`(`login_id`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3`, `postcode`, `phone`, `email`) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']}','{$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']}','{$_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']}', '$ad1', '$ad2', '$ad3', '$postcode', '$phone', '{$_SESSION['email']}');";   
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT user.login_id, customer.customer_id, customer.email FROM user, customer
    WHERE user.login_id = customer.login_id  AND customer.login_id= .'{$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']}'.";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $login = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_CUSTOMER_ID']= $login['customer_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_CUSTOMER_EMAIL']= $login['email'];
            session_write_close();

            header("location: calendar.php");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql_*` functions, they are old and the deprecation process has started. For alternatives look into **PDO** or **mysqli** - these will provide better security and full support from the community. I suggest you start by removing any `@` symbols to uncover underlying error messages.

Comment: Which part is failing?  The first `if ($result)` or the second?  You might get more useful information if you don't suppress the errors from `mysql_query`.

Comment: Do you get any errors from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: You have to     $result variables, and the second is wrapped in the otherone, just telling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT query is successful but the subsequent SELECT fails because it has a syntax error. When using the `{}` syntax in strings, don't use the concatenation `.` character.

Change to

```
$qry="SELECT user.login_id, customer.customer_id, customer.email FROM user, customer WHERE user.login_id = customer.login_id  AND customer.login_id= '{$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']}'";
```

Or concatenate without the `{}` syntax:

```
$qry="SELECT user.login_id, customer.customer_id, customer.email FROM user, customer WHERE user.login_id = customer.login_id  AND customer.login_id= '" . $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If this query fails:

```
$result=mysql_query($qry);
```

Then the next line:

```
if($result) {
```

will result in the `else` bit being used i.e.

```
die("Query failed");
```

So check of errors in your `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra dot in your second query:

```
                                                             Here
                                                                |
                                                                |
                                                                v
WHERE user.login_id = customer.login_id  AND customer.login_id= .'{$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']}'.";
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thing to point out here:

- You should not be using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.  You should look at using mysqli or PDO
- There is no reason at all for your second SELECT query.  You already just inserted all that information into the table. You only thing new is the login_id, which I am assuming is an autoincrement field.  You can get this after the first query by simply calling `mysql_insert_id()`
- Your original problem is that you are likley getting an SQL syntax error here:

`$qry="SELECT user.login_id, customer.customer_id, customer.email FROM user, customer WHERE user.login_id = customer.login_id  AND customer.login_id= .'{$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']}'.";`

Note that your periods and single quotes are going to be literally included in the string.  You should use:

```
$qry="SELECT user.login_id, customer.customer_id, customer.email FROM user, customer
   WHERE user.login_id = customer.login_id  AND customer.login_id = {$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']}";
```